# Visual Studio and code not recognizing NuGet install packageI

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I had a project that was written some time ago that utilized a few NuGet packages and was working great.  Today I had to clone the repo to update it and noticed that the NuGet package that was working perfect was now had red lines stating it couldn’t find the packages.  I looked at the installed packages via the NuGet manager and all appeared ok.  I uninstalled the packages and reinstalled them.  The packages reinstalled fine, but the using statements that were working still refuse to see the installed packages???

Has anyone experienced this and or have any idea what could cause this how to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a quirk. Close visual studio delete bin and obj directories. Also this might be a resharper cache issue if the program actually compiles.

Comment: Nope, just tried that and still get the line errors as if i don't have these packages install... Just weird...